# Swagger not generating api model value

Tags: jersey, jetty, swagger

I'm using swagger to document my REST api.

I wan't to automatically generate the documentation, so I'm using swagger-jaxrs with annotations.

```
@GET
@Path("/news/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "News found",  response = NewsEntry.class)})
```

NewsEntry is my model, and it's setted up as following:

```
@ApiModel("News Entry")
public class NewsEntry {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "the id of the item", required = true)
    private static long id;
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "content", required = true)
    private static String content;

}
```

After a few tests, I found out that, if there is not getters/setters in NewsEntry, it doesn't crashes, however, it generates an empty model... Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

This is my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8 </version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8 </version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8 </version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8 </version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you are using some jaxrs1 implementation.
Thus only one package usage should be enough in the pom

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

its an combined package as you can see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs/1.5.0

Did you try creating referencing another model instead of the NewsEntry.class? 
Did you follow the tutorial and annotate the needed classes with the corresponding annotations? Before 1.5.8. was `@Api`

Else did you use the correct package scanning like in the tutorial?
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5